# How do I output Data from MySQL using Java?

Tags: java, mysql

I'm new at coding (JAVA) and I'm doing my project at the moment and I'm facing a serious issue, that's I couldn't output my DB as CSV.

We need to use Java to control MySQl using Insert, find, update, and delete functions. I've got no problems with these functions and I've finished the codes.

The last step is to output the data from MySQL and output the altered DB (after using update, delete...functions). Using MySQL to output the data might be easier but unfortunately we were required to use Java to do this.

The thing is I can output the CSV file but the result isn't what I want. I expect to see something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdBVv.jpg)

but instead, this is what was saved to my local laptop:

```
    package MidteramWork2;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class OutPutCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sql = "select * from 台北市餐廳名單";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Restaurant?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                    "root", "password");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream("/Users/elenahu/Desktop/SaveFile/台北市餐廳名單.csv");
                InputStream bin=rs.getBinaryStream(6);
                int in;
                while((in=bin.read())!=-1) {
                    fo.write(in);
                }
                fo.flush();
                fo.close();
                bin.close();
            }
            
    

    conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jclBo.jpg)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You have made a number of mistakes:

- You are opening the output file for each row in the resultSet.  Each time you do that you are **overwriting** whatever you wrote for the previous row.
- You are only outputting one column; i.e. the column whose index is 6.

In addition, you are not generating the CSV properly:

- You are not outputting a header line with column names.
- You are not outputting CSV separators (commas)
- You are not testing if the values need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

In while loop the below line creates a new file everytime hence only last executed statement record is available.

FileOutputStream fo = new ...

Here is a code by which you can fetch the results in csv format.
Just replace the values of table,db and filePath.

```
public class OutPutCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sql = "select * from <tablename>";
        try {
            String filePath = "<YourFile>.csv";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<DBName>?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8",
                    "root", "password");
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs=pstmt.executeQuery();
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

            List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int i=1;i<=rsmd.getColumnCount();i++) {
                res.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i));
            }
            //write headers to file 
            writeToFile(res, filePath);
            while(rs.next()) {
                res.clear();
                for(int i=1;i<=rsmd.getColumnCount();i++) {
                    res.add(rs.getString(i));
                }
                //write records to file 
                writeToFile(res, filePath);
            }
    conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void writeToFile(List<String> list, String path) {
        BufferedWriter out;
        try {
            File file = new File(path);
            out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
            String line = String.join(",",list);
            out.write(line);
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much. It worked. But I'm not sure why. Is it possible to ask you if there's any easier way to do this?

Comment: The issues has been  pointed by @stephen C Check that.